# how to create a join relation using elasticsearch python client

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking for any examples that implement the parent-child relationship using the python interface.

I can define a mapping such as

```
es.indices.create(
  index= "docpage",
  body= {
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
         "my_join_field": { 
           "type": "join",
           "relations": {
             "my_document": "my_page" 
           }
         }
        }
      }
    }
)
```

I am then indexing a document using

```
res = es.index(index="docpage",doc_type="_doc",id = 1, body=jsonDict) ,
```

where jsonDict is a dict structure of document's text,
`jsonDict['my_join_field']= 'my_document'`, and other relevant info.

[Reference example.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-parent-id-query.html)

I tried adding `pageDict` where the page is a string containing text on a page in a document, and

```
pageDict['content']=page
pageDict['my_join_field']={}
pageDict['my_join_field']['parent']="1"
pageDict['my_join_field']['name']="page"

res = es.index(index="docpage",doc_type="_doc",body=pageDict)
```

but I get a parser error:

> RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'failed to parse')

Any ideas?

Comment: sorry, pageDict['my_join_field']['name']='my_page'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me :
res=es.index(index="docpage",doc_type="_doc",body={"content":page,
                                                   "my-join-field":{
                                                       "name": "my_page",
                                                       "parent": "1"}
                                                   })

Answer (score 0):

The initial syntax can work if the parent is also repeated in the "routing" key of the main query body:

```
res = es.index(index="docpage",doc_type="_doc",body=pageDict, routing=1)
```